# Inline CSS from the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A fresh Rails application has the following code in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` to include a link to the - in production - minified CSS:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

For the reason of WebPerformance I'd like to use the asset pipeline to minify and organize my CSS but inline it in the header.

How can I tell Rails to inline the CSS of the asset pipeline in the `application.html.erb`?

Comment: Looking at the AMP spec and their Github, it looks like a major component  of the page load speed advantage is to eliminate CSS loading altogether by inlining styles on AMP pages. It looks like you'll be inlining CSS snippets throughout your code and eliminating the CSS part of the asset pipeline altogether, not wrapping it up in AMP--that would seem to defeat the purpose of AMP, which is to eliminate entirely CSS file load time. From a quick assessment,  I would suggest creating a Rails Engine that would host your AMP pages and omit the the asset pipeline from the engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do the trick:

```
<style>
  <% css = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public#{asset_path("application", type: :stylesheet)}") %>
  <%= css.html_safe %>
</style>
```